# MySql query that contains unique list of all matching queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two entities, `folder` and `document`. `document` belongs to `folder`, and I have a many to may table like this`:

| folder_id | document_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |

I need to find all the `folder_id`s of folders that contain all of the `document_id`s that I pass as an array.

So for example, if I pass `[11, 12]` the result will be `[2]`, as that is the only folder that contains both documents.

It still returns the folder even though it contains document `13` that isn't in the array.

The number of documents is around 1,000, and the number of folders somewhere in the 3 million range.

I've tried code like this:

```
select folder_id 
from folder_document 
where document_id in (11, 12)
group by folder_id  
having count(document_id) = 2 // ie array length
```

**Edit**
By array I just mean what is shown in the example query, ie `(11, 12)`. So for example I would have a function like:

```php
public function foo(array $arrayOfDocumentIds) 
{
  // array is added to the query by doing implode(', ', $arrayOfDocumentIds) or whatever
  $query = // this is what I don't know how to build

  $idsOfFoldersThatContainAllTheDocuments = $databaseService->execute($query);

  return $idsOfFoldersThatContainAllTheDocuments;
}
```

Comment: *that I pass as an array* MySQL have no ARRAY datatype. Do you mean JSON value which contains an array? If so then you may use `WHERE NOT EXISTS (NOT MEMBER OF)`.

Comment: Could you provide more details on the nature of your *array* in your MySQL environment? Are these values stored inside a table? stored as JSON (as Akina suggested)? @forrestedw

Comment: By array I just mean what is shown in the example query, ie `(11, 12)`

Comment: I've added more info to the question. The array bit isn't important, I just need to know what query to use

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a sorted list of the `document_id`s as a comma separated string, like `'11,12'` then you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT folder_id
FROM folder_document
GROUP BY folder_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(document_id ORDER BY document_id) = '11,12';
```

Or, if the above case is not possible:

```
SELECT folder_id
FROM folder_document
GROUP BY folder_id
HAVING SUM(document_id IN (11, 12)) = 2
   AND SUM(document_id NOT IN (11, 12)) = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1aa0733e49e0b20de7381df9b18dbc57).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "*folder_id*" values, that exactly have only the documents in your condition, by excluding all those "*folder_id*" values which don't have those documents.

```
SELECT folder_id 
FROM folder_document 
WHERE document_id IN (11, 12)
  AND folder_id NOT IN (
      SELECT folder_id 
      FROM folder_document 
      WHERE document_id NOT IN (11, 12)     
  )
GROUP BY folder_id  
HAVING COUNT(document_id) = 2
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5t9HZ8jNPF8w211GYeDihY/0).